# How do I fix the error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Name.Entity.Models.MakeModelInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm trying to validate several user input fields that use type-ahead. I want to reject any input that's not contained in the type-ahead list.

But I'm getting a build error on the 'var isValid' line of code when I try to run my application:

**My ViewModel**

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [AllowedModelMake(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Make from the list.")]   //JosephW
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string MakePlaceholder { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [AllowedModelMake(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Model from the list.")]   //JosephW
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string ModelPlaceholder { get; set; }
```

**My Controller**

```
public class AllowedModelMakeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        // Validate that user input is in the list of allowed values
        var allowedList = MakeModelHelpers.GetActiveMakeModelInfo();

        var userInput = value as string;

        var isValid = allowedList.Contains(userInput);   //<- ERROR IS HERE

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

The return type for GetActiveMakeModelInfo() is here:

```
public static List<MakeModelInfo> GetActiveMakeModelInfo() {
    return makeModelRepository.GetActiveInfo();
```

The string representation of MakeModelInfo is:

```
namespace Name.Entity.Models {
    public class MakeModelInfo {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
    }
}
```

According to the Microsoft documentation at [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation/) this should work.

I'm pretty new at .Net and I'm not sure how to fix this problem. Can anyone offer a suggestion?

Comment: What is the returntype of GetActiveMakeModelInfo? It seems that it doesnt return a collection of strings but a collection of makemodelinfo

Comment: I edited my questions with the return type. Please forgive my lack of experience, but I could use some help understand why that impacts my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you are comparing `MakeModelInfo` to a `string`, which doesn't work. How to fix it? Compare apples to apples and pears to pears :)

Comment: @Erwin Damsma How would I convert MakeModelInfo to a string so I can do a valid compare?

Comment: @csharpMind well ... you tell us, how do you really? what is the string representation of `MakeModelInfo`?

Comment: @csharpMind Edit your question and add the code for the MakeModelInfo class. Then, you're likely to get more direction.

Comment: @Erwin Damsma, @ oerkelens.  Ofir Winegarten, thank you for responding. I edited my question above to show the string representation of MakeModelInfo. Again, I'm sorry if I seem a bit slow, but I'm brand new to .Net and programming in general. I'm still trying to wrap my head around how everything works. I appreciate your patience.

Comment: @csharpMind There's still not enough information in the question. how do the user input look like? You have showed us the class definition, but it is certainly not the string representation - how would you implement `ToString()` for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing what you're really trying to check is if the user input (a string) exists in the "Allowed" list of MakeModelInfo. You already know you can't compare an object to a string, so the Contains method won't work. What you can do is something like this:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    // Validate that user input is in the list of allowed values
    var allowedList = MakeModelHelpers.GetActiveMakeModelInfo();

    var userInput = value as string;

    var isValid = allowedList.Any(i -> i.Make == userInput || i.Model == userInput);

    return isValid;
}
```

You can modify this if you're only interested in checking one of the properties and not both. Alternatively, what you might want to do is use one drop down containing the Makes of vehicle that is in your list and another containing the Models for the selected Make. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2012/01/09/cascading-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc/) is an example.

Comment: I finally got it working based on the information I got from your post Matt. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

on this line:

```
var isValid = allowedList.Contains(userInput);   //<- ERROR IS HERE
```

You are missing the point here. `Contains()` method has different overloading functions. You are using `ICollection<T>.Contains(T)`, which means the type of list and the type of argument is the same. So, in above code, compiler thinks `userInput` has the same type i.e. `MakeModelInfo`.

You should use `ICollection<T>.Contains(Predicate(T))`, it takes lambda expression and in that you can check for the property value. e.g.

```
var isValid = allowedList.Contains(x=> x.Make.Equals(userInput));
//OR
var isValid = allowedList.Contains(x=> x.Model.Equals(userInput));
```

If the `allowedList` contains any item having property `Make or Model` equal to `userInput`, it will return `true or false`